# Safety of context aware inner class

Tags: java

I want to ask about the safety of having an inner class use its own reference in the outer class.

Here's the example:

```
public class OuterClass {

    InnerClass Foo1;
    InnerClass Foo2;
    static OuterClass outer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        outer = new OuterClass();
        outer.test();
    }

    public void test() {
        Foo1 = new InnerClass();
        Foo2 = new InnerClass();
        Foo1.printfoo();
        Foo2.printfoo();
    }

    private class InnerClass {

        String foo;

        public InnerClass() {
        }

        private void printfoo() {
            if(OuterClass.this.Foo1.equals(this)){
                foo = "foo1";
            }
            if(OuterClass.this.Foo2.equals(this)) {
                foo = "foo2";
            }
            System.out.println(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

So, this is my question, is this safe? And/or is there a better way?

The goal here is to initialize the fields of inner class with the correct values for it's intended use in the outer class without the outer class needing to provide any information to the inner class.

Comment: safe in what respect?

Comment: Could this cause a runtime error, or throw an exception if a user tried to call the inner class in a common way?

Comment: The class is private so it can only be used from within `OuterClass` or `InnerClass`. What "common way" are you thinking of?